# Prolog. Does not create a list

Tags: prolog, visual-prolog

I want to create a list consisting of `N` elements.
I write the following code:

```
DOMAINS
    list = integer*
PREDICATES
    create(integer, integer, list)
CLAUSES
    create(_, 0, []).

    create(Start, End, [Start|T]):-
        Start < End + 1,!,
        Counter = Start + 1,
        create(Counter, End, T).
GOAL
    create(1, 5, L).
```

But it returns me `No Solution`.

On the other hand if I change the direction of my `Counter` like this:

```
DOMAINS
    list = integer*
PREDICATES
    create(integer,list)
CLAUSES
    create(0,[]).

    create(N,[N|T]):-
        N > 0,
        NN = N - 1,
        create(NN,T).
GOAL
    create(5,L).
```

It returns me 1 Solution: `L=[5,4,3,2,1]`. It's working good, but not in the order.
What wrong in my first variant of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make some adjustments to your program:

1. The stop clause is never unified, because you don't decrement the
   End term.
2. Counter need to be evaluated to the expression Start + 1, so use the is/2 operator.
3. You don't need the cut on the second clause, but on the first one.

Program:

```
create(X, X, [X]):- !.
create(Start, End, [Start|T]):-
        Start =\= End,
        Counter is Start + 1,
        create(Counter, End, T).
```

Consult(You need the list to be instantiated, so use a variable instead of the empty list)

```
?- create(1,5, L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first variant the base case is wrong:

```
create(_, 0, []).
```

Here the `End` argument is 0, but your non-base rule is never modifying the `End`, it is running on `Start`.
So your base case should match whenever `Start` is equal to the `End`:

```
create(E, E, []).
```